# Error in a simple C code (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

In the follwoing code, using libxml libraries :

```
key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur3->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                        image2 = key;
                        printf("the image 2 is %s \n", image2);
                        flag = 2;
                }
                if(flag == 0)
                {
                        image1 = key;
                        printf("the image 1 is %s \n", image1);
                        flag = 1;
                }
                    //printf("SRC of the file is: %s\n", key);

                xmlFree(key);
            printf("the image 1 is %s \n", image1);
```

the two printf are giving me different outputs.

The output is :

```
the image 1 is 1.png 
the image 1 is 0p�  g 
the image 2 is 2.png 
the image 1 is 0p�  g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the line `image1 = key`, `image1`  and `key`point to the same memory area.

I suppose `xmlFree(key);` alter this memory area.
If you want the content of this string survive to the xmlFree, you should consider using the function [strcpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy) before deallocationg the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what are `image1` and `key`? I guess pointers (because of the tag and because of the function name + the c-tag). If so, the problem is with calling `xmlFree(key);` before calling `printf` - both `key` and `image1` point to the same place of memory (if the are pointers ), so that's the problem. Put `xmlFre(key)` after the `printf`.

Also you should add `else` in front of the second if (:

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see it from that short piece of undocumented code, it does not really make sense to call xmlfree(), which converts for example 1.png to 0p�  g.

but the real reason why the var image1 is changed is because image1 is a reference to key, which then is update by calling xmlfree(key).